# Why is RsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString throwing a WindowsCryptographicException about a file being in use?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cryptography

I am using the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider) class from .NET 6 to do some signing operations and am running into an unknown WindowsCryptoGraphicException when loading key information from an XML string.

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.ImportKeyBlob(SafeProvHandle saveProvHandle, CspProviderFlags flags, Boolean addNoSaltFlag, Byte[] keyBlob, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportCspBlob(Byte[] keyBlob)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.FromXmlString(String xmlString)
```

The exception above occurs seemingly randomly on remote servers during high loads, which makes it hard to reproduce. The application does signing many times across many parallel threads.

I cannot share the code itself, but the relevant execution path can be simplified as follows:

```
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Example
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("Windows")]
    internal class ExampleClass
    {
        public static byte[] CreateSignature()
        {
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rSACryptoServiceProvider = CreateRSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world!");
                    byte[] hash = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(bytes);

                    RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter formatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rSACryptoServiceProvider);
                    formatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");
                
                    byte[] signatureBytes = formatter.CreateSignature(hash);
                    return signatureBytes;
                }
            }
        }

        public static RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateRSACryptoServiceProvider()
        {
            var privateKeyXml = RetrievePrivateKeyInformationXml();

            var cspParameters = new CspParameters()
            {
                Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
                KeyContainerName = "SomeName"
            };

            var rSACryptoServiceProvider =  new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParameters);

            rSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(privateKeyXml); // <-- THIS THROWS THE EXCEPTION!

            return rSACryptoServiceProvider;
        }

        public static string RetrievePrivateKeyInformationXml()
        {
            // private key information should always be the same as it is tied to the hostproces.
            // please generate your own key using the RSACryptoServiceProvider.ToXmlString(true) method
            return "some private key information";
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is called many times across many different parallel threads. Note that the private key is actually retrieved from a remote service. I am simply illustrating a constant private key in this example as these threads use the same private key. Every thread creates a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class during signing.

Does anyone have advice on what the underlying cause of this exception could be? I attempted to consult the documentation from Microsoft, however this specific exception does not appear to be documented in any documentation that I could find.

I believe this error may be caused by the RSA key container files not being thread-safe when accessed through the RSACryptoServiceProvider in the Windows file system. If my belief is correct, how would one ensure that parallel threads can use the construct above to access the key container file?

Comment: Are you running F'-in' McAfee?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes No we are not. It could be an antivirus scanning it. However, it does occur frequently only at high loads so the antivirus should not be a likely cause. I'll check it just in case.